# Apache Wicket: Injecting dependencies in Session (using Guice)

Tags: session, wicket, guice

I'm using the [Wicket Auth/Roles](http://wicket.apache.org/learn/projects/authroles.html) and I ran into the same problem as the OP of [this thread](http://apache-wicket.1842946.n4.nabble.com/Wicket-Guice-Inject-into-Session-td1882841.html).

I need to access the DB service layer in the [`AuthenticatedWebSession`](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.5/org/apache/wicket/authroles/authentication/AuthenticatedWebSession.html) (for user authentication). I followed [Steve Flasby's suggestion](http://apache-wicket.1842946.n4.nabble.com/Wicket-Guice-Inject-into-Session-tp1882841p1882853.html) and did the following:

```
@Override
public Session newSession(Request request, Response response) {
    Session s = new MySession(request);
    mInjector.inject(s);
    return s;
}
```

Unfortunately this results in

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: EntityManager is closed
```

(presumably due to the fact that (a) I'm using open session in view, and (b) the session spans over several requests).

I solved this by moving the injection into the `AuthenticatedWebSession.authenticate` method.

```
@Override
public boolean authenticate(String username, String pass) {

    Injector.get().inject(this);

    ...
}
```

I suspect that this is not best practice, because now I need to access to the service layer in other methods too, and it doesn't seem like a good idea to add `Injector.get().inject(this)` in each such method.

### My question:

How do I perform injection into the session object upon each request? (Or, if this is a bad approach all together, how do I access the service layer in the [`AuthenticatedWebSession`](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.5/org/apache/wicket/authroles/authentication/AuthenticatedWebSession.html)?)

Comment: Do you use `Stateless` beans?

Comment: Isn't that a Spring thing? (I'm using guice.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can implement `IRequestCycleListener` (extend `AbstractRequestCycleListener`) and implement:

```
@Override
public void onBeginRequest(RequestCycle cycle)
{
        if (Session.exists()) {
            Injector.get().inject(Session.get());
        }
}
```

Register your `IRequestCycleListener` in `Application#init()` with `getRequestCycleListeners().add(new YourRequestCycleListener())`.

Comment: Aah, thank you. Precisely what I was looking for. Regarding the last part. I read the following *"The wicket-guice project will take care of proxying the injected beans so that your pages can be serialized safely."* ([here](http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples/guice/)). Does this mean that I don't need to worry about detaching the service?

Comment: You're right, you get just some proxies which are serializable. I'll remove that part from my answer.

Comment: Again, thanks for your answer. I posted a follow-up question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17285304/apache-wicket-injecting-dependencies-in-form-validators-using-guice).